# MacOS Terninal \u as username -2

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-sierra

The user name in my MacOS terminal shows as `username-2`, while I don't know the `-2`

```
Last login: Mon Sep  3 17:59:39 on ttys001
501 HacSec-2:hacsec ~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer and fixed my terminal username to normal by using the following command:

```
# sudo scutil --set HostName (Add Your Username Here)
```

more information at [this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal)